# Why am I getting this error in proteus: " Invalid opcode 0xFFFF at PC=0x002A"

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr, atmega32

I wrote this code for avr atmega328P in assembly language. It turns on and off an LED using a push button, but in proteus I am getting this error:

> Invalid opcode 0xFFFF at PC=0x002A

This is my code:

```
.INCLUDE "M328Pdef.inc"


ldi r16,HIGH(RAMEND)
out SPH, R16
ldi r16,LOW(RAMEND)
out SPL, R16

start:
ldi r16,0xFF
out DDRB,r16
ldi r17,0x00
out DDRD,r17
ldi r21,0x00
ldi r23,0x01

Forever:
in r20,PIND
cp r20,r21
BREQ ledon
cp r20,r23
BREQ ledoff
rjmp Forever


ledon:
ldi r22,0x01
out PORTB,r22 
ret

ledoff:
ldi r24,0x00
out PORTB,r24
ret
```

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
BREQ ledon  ; branch
cp r20,r23
BREQ ledoff ; branch
rjmp Forever

ledon:
ldi r22,0x01
out PORTB,r22 
ret ; return from subroutine, but never used [R]CALL.

ledoff:
ldi r24,0x00
out PORTB,r24
ret ; return from subroutine, but never used [R]CALL.
```

You are branching to `ledon` resp. `ledoff`, which is just a conditional jump.  But at the end of the respective blocks, you are using `ret` as if you called the code by means of `[r]call`.

The `ret` will pop 2 bytes from the stack and use these as a word-address to return to.  The code target will very likely have uninitialized flash, which holds 0xff's, and two 0xff's are 0xffff which is not a legal AVR opcode. 0x002a is the byte-address of the last `ret` which issued the illegal jump.

To fix, you could `rjmp Forever` instead of `ret`, but it depends on what you want to achieve with the code.