getting "Invalid opcode 0xFFFF at PC=0x5200" on proteus
this is my code for atmega32 in assembly language. It  will toggle led on pd5 after pressing the push button 10 times, but in proteus I am getting this error:

Invalid opcode 0xFFFF at PC=0x5200

I have attached a picture of my circuit on proteus 8:

This is my code:
.include "m32def.inc"             

.equ memory = 0x200   
.equ timer1 = 0x00FF  

.cseg
.org 0x00                         
rjmp RESET                        

RESET:
    ; Initializing packet counter

ldi r16, 0x00                 
ldi r30, LOW(memory)  
ldi r31, HIGH(memory) 
st Z, r16                     ; Store 0 at memory using Z

    ; Making Port D as output

ldi r16, 0xFF                 
out DDRD, r16                 
ldi r16, 0x00                 
out PORTD, r16                

    ; Setting up Timer1 in CTC mode

ldi r16, (1 << WGM12)         ; Load value to configure Timer1 in CTC mode
out TCCR1B, r16               ; Set Timer1 to CTC mode
ldi r16, (1 << CS12)          ; Load prescaler value to slow down the timer (prescaler of 256)
out TCCR1B, r16               ; Start Timer1 with the prescaler
ldi r16, timer1   
out OCR1AL, r16               ; Set Timer1 compare match value low byte
ldi r16, 0x00                 
out OCR1AH, r16               ; Set Timer1 compare match value high byte
ldi r16, (1 << OCIE1A)        ; Enable Timer1 compare match interrupt
out TIMSK, r16                ; Enable Timer1 interrupt in the interrupt mask register
sei                           ; Enable global interrupts


    ; Timer1 Compare Match Interrupt Service Routine

TIMER1_COMPA_ISR:
ldi r30, LOW(memory)  
ldi r31, HIGH(memory) 
ld r17, Z                     
inc r17                       
cpi r17, 10                   
brne CONTINUE_COUNT            
ldi r18, (1 << 5)             
out PORTD, r18                
ldi r17, 0x00                 
st Z, r17                     
out PORTD, r16                

CONTINUE_COUNT:
st Z, r17                  
reti     

the code in avr is running, on proteus i was expecting the led to toggle after pressing the push button 10 times, but i receive this error.

May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552075/why-am-i-getting-this-error-in-proteus-invalid-opcode-0xffff-at-pc-0x0008

Where do you think the ISR jumps?
Now you just have reset interrupt vector that basically hops on the next word right after it...
When Timer interrupt happens, it'll jumps in the middle of your code and reenable ISR
I'd expect something like this:
.org 0x0000
    rjmp RESET
.org OC1Aaddr               ; 0x000e
    rjmp TIMER1_COMPA_ISR      
.org INT_VECTORS_SIZE

RESET:
    ;  ...

You can also define all unused interrupt vectors and direct them to something like BAD_ISR
